# Uniform acceleration (easy question)

Tags: applications

Two stunt drivers drive their cars along a straight horizontal road. The first car is travelling at $30$ m/s and is followed by the second car, $16$ m behind it, both cars are travelling with equal speeds. At an instant the driver of the first car applies the brakes decelerating at $3$ m/s/s. Two seconds later , the second car brakes and decelerates at $4$ m/s/s. The time it takes the cars to collide?. 
$$s1: 30t-1.5t^2+16$$   $$s2:30(t+2)-2(t+2)^2$$
$s1=s2 -b$ formula and $t=3.66$ rounded to 2 decimal places
Just not sure of my answer can someone plz check my answer, Thank u.

Comment: You should show the steps you went through.  It is easier to check work than reproduce it, and if you have made an error we can identify it.

Comment: You should not have $t+2$ in either of the places you have it. It says that whatever formula you plug it into has been acting for two seconds _longer_ than the time elapsed since the first car started braking.

Comment: so should it be 30(t+2)-2t^2

Comment: No. See what happens at $t=0$, for example: your formula says the second car is at $60$ while the first is at $16$--how did the second car end up ahead?

Comment: Also look at what the second car is doing. For $2$ seconds it moves at constant speed. Then afterwards it moves at a decreasing speed (decelerating). You cannot express both kinds of motion in a single formula like $s=s_0 + vt + \frac12 at^2.$ You'll need one calculation to say what happens for the first two seconds, another one to say what happens afterward.

Comment: Of course you can $s=s_0+vt+1/2a{ONE}(t-2)^2$, where $ONE(t)$ is 1 for $t>0$ and zero for $t<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation let $d_1, d_2$ be the distance the cars 1 and 2 pass before the collision.
$d_1=30t-3t^2/2$, $d_2=30t-4(t-2)^2/2$
We know that $d2=d1+16$
So 
we get the following equation
$$
30t-4(t-2)^2/2=16+30t-3t^2/2 
$$
So regrouping:
$$
-2t^2-8+8t=16-3t^2/2 \to ~ t^2+48-16t=0
$$
The solution $t=4$ and $12$, but the feasible solution obviously is the first one. So $t=4s$
Remark : if u want to know the time since the second car starts the  deacceleration then $t=t-2=2$

The simplest check. The fist car starts to slow down. For 2 sec it passes $60-3*2^2/2=54 m$
The second car passes $60m$.For the next 2 sec the first car passes $24*2-3 2^2/2=42m$. The second car passes $30*2-4*2^2/2=52m$. So the first car passes $96$ and the second car:$112=96+16$.